# Probema al sobrecargar less al contenedor Set

Tags: c++

Hola quisiera saber porqué en el set "cjnt2", a la hora de imprimir parece que está guardando el elemento {"alias2",2} cuando según el operador que he sobrecargado debería eliminarlo del Set cjnt2. Gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
struct contestant {
    string name;
    int money;
    bool operator<(const contestant &other) const {
        return name != other.name && money >= other.money;
    }
};

int main() {

  set<contestant> cjnt2;

 cjnt2 = { 
     {"alias9", 10},
    {"alias2", 11},
    {"alias2", 2},
    {"alias3", 20},
    {"alias8", 10},
    {"alias1", 10} 
  };

    for (auto a: cjnt2)
    cout << a.name<< " "<< a.money << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te añade ambos elementos porque la función no hace lo que se espera de ella.

De acuerdo con la documentación de `set`:

> two objects a and b are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)

Es decir, dos objetos se considerarán equivalentes si `a<b == false` y `b<a == false`.

Eso en teoría se verifica bien... pero el orden de comparación de elementos es igualmente importante...

Vamos a retocar un poco la función para ver qué sucede:

```
bool operator<(const contestant &other) const
{
    std::cout << "(" << name << " " << money << ") vs (" << other.name << " " << other.money << ") = " << (name != other.name && money >= other.money? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << '\n';
    return name != other.name && money >= other.money;
}
```

Si ejecutamos el código, vemos qu eel `set` está generando las siguientes comparaciones:

```
(alias9 10) vs (alias2 11) = FALSE
(alias2 11) vs (alias9 10) = TRUE
(alias2 11) vs (alias9 10) = TRUE
(alias9 10) vs (alias2 2) = TRUE
(alias2 2) vs (alias9 10) = FALSE
(alias2 2) vs (alias3 20) = FALSE
(alias3 20) vs (alias9 10) = TRUE
(alias3 20) vs (alias2 11) = TRUE
(alias3 20) vs (alias2 11) = TRUE
(alias2 2) vs (alias8 10) = FALSE
(alias8 10) vs (alias9 10) = TRUE
(alias8 10) vs (alias2 11) = FALSE
(alias2 11) vs (alias8 10) = TRUE
(alias8 10) vs (alias2 11) = FALSE
(alias2 2) vs (alias1 10) = FALSE
(alias1 10) vs (alias9 10) = TRUE
(alias1 10) vs (alias2 11) = FALSE
(alias1 10) vs (alias8 10) = TRUE
(alias2 11) vs (alias1 10) = TRUE
(alias1 10) vs (alias8 10) = TRUE
```

Si nos centramos en las que nos interesan:

```
(alias9 10) vs (alias2 2) = TRUE
(alias2 2) vs (alias9 10) = FALSE
(alias2 2) vs (alias3 20) = FALSE
```

Vemos que en ningún momento se ha comparado `(alias2 2)` con `(alias2 11)`. Simplemente ha salido que `(alias2 2)` es menor que `(alias3 20)`  y ahí ha dejado de comparar... el objeto que pretendes eliminar ya ha encontrado su sitio en el `set`!!!

¿Y por qué no ha llegado a comparar con `(alias2 11)`?

Precisamente porque el valor de `money` provoca cambios en las comparaciones:

```
(alias2 11) vs (alias9 10) = TRUE
(alias2 2) vs (alias9 10) = FALSE
```

Dado que esta primera comparación es diferente, en la lista de elementos contra los que se comprueba `(alias2 2)` no va a estar nunca `(alias2 11)`:

```
 (alias2 11) < (alias9 10) < (alias2 2)
```

Pues bien, basta con retocar ligeramente la función para que todo funcione:

```
bool operator<(const contestant &other) const
{
    return name < other.name;
}
```

Hemos eliminado de la comparación la variable `money` ya que si no admitimos nombres duplicados, el valor de `money` es irrelevante.

Comment: Con lo que al final, en realidad con un `std::map` basta.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster sí, es otra forma de verlo